# How to understand the language used to describe statistics in the book "The Rise and Decline of Nations"

Tags: regression, nonparametric

The tables on pages 102 - 108 are supposed to compare the growth rate and union membership between confederate and non-confederate states since 1965 (I believe it's since 1965 but it's so confusing I can't tell for sure). A legend is provided that does not help me decipher the table in the slightest. There is no distinction I can discern between the statistics belonging to confederate and non-confederate states. Let's take the first statistic on page 103 as an example; the first statistic is listed as:

MFG = 12.6801 - 5.5427 STACIV1 R2 = .54

The legend defines the following:

MFG: Exponential rate of growth of manufacturing income during 1965 - 1978

YEAR : For confederate -- 100

For non-confederate -- length of time since statehood

(I don't even know what the term YEAR here is trying to define, "For confederate -- 100" 100 what? Kangaroos?)

178 = 1965 - 1787 (earliest year of statehood) (This is just saying that the state must of been established between these years, I know that much)

STACIV1 = YEAR/178

I don't know what any of this means. What is R2 saying? This is another language to me and it's just disappointing that I can't interpret this table because the author prefaced this chapter as a preparation for how statistics are applied to economic phenomenon, but he does not do a very good job at that and I don't even know what to google to even find out what it is I have to learn to understand this table. If anyone can, please help.

Comment: First of all, it's unrealistic to expect that any of us will have access to Mancur Olsen's book and are, therefore, able to inspect *pages 102-108*. Next, the book was published in 1984 and is primarily an economics text, not a statistical one. So, the field of economics has undergone tremendous change, both quantitatively and theoretically, in the years since publication, not to mention that Olsen is no longer with us. Your question is better posed on SE's Econometrics site.

Comment: First of all, the question is separable from the book that's why another user on this stack besides yourself was able to answer it. You are dwelling on irrelevant details instead of focusing on the relevant statistical question at hand. Yes the book is about economics, but my question is not about economics; it's about statistics more specifically statistical notation. Reading the answer to my question here will help you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope by explaining the notation in your example I will help elucidate the notation generally.

What you include is a model to predict the exponential rate of growth for manufacturing income. Many online sources explain exponential growth better than I can, but make sure you understand that first ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth)). The model seems to be predicting the value of the growth rate parameter, which describes how quickly the manufacturing income grows year to year. The model predicts this value based on what fraction of the maximum possible years a state has been a member of the union. The model says you can estimate the exponential growth rate for a given state, $r$, with the equation: $$r=12.6801 - 5.5427\times \frac{\text{years_in_union}}{178}$$
Apparently the author applies this model even to states that never joined the union. For those states, because there is no value for $\text{years_in_union}$, the author uses the value of $100$ instead.

As for R2, that is actually $R^2$, which signifies the coefficient of determination. Again, better sources than me explain what this represents exactly, but simply put, it describes how much of the variation in the data is explained by the model. This is an indicator of how well your model explains the data, which designates how good it is. Higher values for $R^2$ generally mean the model does a better job of explaining the observed data.

It's unfortunate the notation in the book isn't more transparent.